# Facebook Feed error with a Facebook user, ok with another

Tags: facebook, feed

I use the feed dialog for sharing on my website.
It works with my personal account, but not with another.

Here is my string:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=my_app_id&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com&picture=http://www.my_domain.com/my_path/my_image.jpg&link=http://www.my_domain.com/news?id=3&name=My%20page%20description

Facebook return simply "An error occurred. Please try again later.".

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding &show_error=true I've got: API Error Code: 1
API Error Description: An unknown error occurred
Error Message: kError 1349040: Invalid App ID: The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID.

Comment: But obviously if I switch between two Facebook users, it don't change nothing to the app id that I've set in the website. The account that share is the one where I've create the app id. It have an influence?

Comment: Make sure your app is live (available to public) by switching the toggle on the Dashboard. Otherwise, it's only available to admins/developers.